# fgets() reads and stores a char form a line twice

Tags: c, string, integer

So I have a file `data.txt`, with random integers written in it, for example `"17 12 5 4 16"`.

So, I used `fgets()` to read this line of integers and store it in a `char str []`. As expected `str [0] == 17`, but `str [1] == 7`, an so on... every 2 digits the integer is stored in an element in the array, but the second digit is also stored in the following element.

**Example:** `str [3] = 12`, `str [4] = 2`, `str[5] = ' '`.

What could be done to fix this issue?

Here is my very typical code:

```
    FILE* fp = fopen ("data.txt", "r");

    int i = 0, j = 0;
    int size = fileSize(fp) + 1; // Enumerate the char numbers in file
    char str [size];
    rewind (fp);
    fgets (str, size, fp);
```

Here is my entire code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>

typedef struct RATIONAL
{
    int top;
    int bottom;
} RATIONAL;

void printArray (int arr [], int count)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i)
    {
        printf ("%d\n", arr[i]);
    }
}

int fileSize (FILE* fp)
{
    char c;
    int i = 0;
    while ((c = getc (fp)) != EOF)
    {
        i++;
    }
    return (i);
}

int main ()
{
    RATIONAL ratArray [23];  //array to hold rational numbers
    int intArray [45]; //array to hold integer values

    FILE* fp = fopen ("data.txt", "r");

    int i = 0, j = 0;
    int size = fileSize(fp) + 1; // Enumerate the char numbers in file
    char str [size];
    rewind (fp);
    fgets (str, size, fp);

    //Convert string to array of ints
    while (i < size -1)
    {
        if (isdigit (str [i]))
        {
                intArray[j++] = atoi(&str[i]);
                i++;
        }
        else
            i++;
    }
        printArray (intArray, intArray[0]);
```

Input: [data.txt](https://1drv.ms/t/s!Avugtf3caxPuiRPfZWTBPvsYODPg?e=IcUo23)

Comment: How do you know what is stored in each array element? How do you find that out?

Comment: Please provide a [minimal verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). That is, the smallest amount of complete code that anyone can run exactly as shown to reproduce the exact problem.

Comment: If by `array[0]` you mean `str[0]` then of course it is only the first digit. You need to extract each `int` and not just read each ascii character.

Comment: When you [edit] your question in order to do what you've been kindly asked in the second comment also provide a minimal `data.txt` file that allows to reproduce the problem. Also tell us what `array` is, there is no such symbol in your code.

Comment: "As expected array [0] == 17," No! `str[0]` contains `'1'` as it can only hold 1 single `char`, not more.

Comment: I don't see any `array` variable in the posted code!? How do you get from the text line held by `str` to the `array`. Seems you have only posted parts of the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you experience is absolutely expected. The key misunderstanding is that you expect `arr[N]` to hold the (N+1)<sup>th</sup> integer as it was an array of integers... but it's not. It is an array of characters.

If you store integers within a `char` array, every digit will *occupy* an array location. So `arr[0]` will contain the most significant digit of the first number and `arr[a]` the least significant digit.

So, in your example, the string `"17 12 5 4 16"` will be stored in this way:

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| 0x31 | 0x37 | 0x20 | 0x31 | 0x32 | 0x20 | 0x35 | 0x20 | 0x34 | 0x20 | 0x31 | 0x36 | 0x00 |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|  '1' |  '7' |  ' ' |  '1' |  '2' |  ' ' |  '5' |  ' ' |  '4' |  ' ' |  '1' |  '7' | '\0' |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

All digits are in the same array and separated by spaces. The string is closed by a string terminator `'\0'`.

Interesting enough, if you print the whole string with `printf("%s\n", arr)` you get

```
17 12 5 4 16
```

but if you try to print passing the address of the second character, with `printf("%s\n", &arr[1])` you get

```
7 12 5 4 16
```

And so on. This means that **C has no idea (not yet) that your intention is to store 5 integers**. The string is one until the string terminator is found (**the space doesn't terminate the string**), so starting from the second digit will just make C print all the string except the first digit.

---

Since you have a string formatted in a well known way and you want an array of integers, you have to parse it to get the integers:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char arr[] = "7 12 5 4 16";

int main()
{
    char * token = strtok(arr, " ");
    while(token != NULL)
    {
        printf("Next int: %d %s\n", atoi(token)); // Here you can assign the value to your array
        token = strtok(NULL, " ");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

In my demonstrative example, in which the input string was a global array instead of something read from a file like in your scenario,  I used [strtok()](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/strtok-strtok_r-functions-c-examples/) (`strtok_r` can be used in case a re-entrant function is required) and I got the integers using the simple `atoi()` (just because the input format was _under control - I recommend using `strtol()` for a better control of the input).

Comment: Thank you very much, that was demonstrated quite well. In response to that new knowledge, I just changed the "i++" to "i+=2" when parsing through my string array, and it worked. I also find the method you've proposed to be more efficient so I'll implement it from now on.

Comment: @omarkhaled feel free to accept the answer if it was helpful to you. ;)